# Does clojure allow line continuations? If so, how?

Tags: clojure

Many languages allow for line continuations, e.g. in VB with the underscore at the end of a line,
or in Tcl with a backslash at the end of a line.

Does Clojure have a way to allow for line continuations?

Thanks,
chasse

Comment: In what situation would you need such a thing? I can't think of one.

Comment: Line continuations are only needed in a language in which defines a newline as a statement/expression *terminator* and where such a statement/expression grammar production cannot be trivially continued per the language rules. This not the case in Clojure.. not sure where this question is from/going.

Comment: Maybe inside a string constant, so that a long constant doesn't go super wide? I just use `str` for that though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clojure does not need "line continuations." It is delimited by parentheses. Just don't close your parentheses, and your current statement will continue.